# Final state behaviour depending on parameters in coupled ODEs

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I have the following set of coupled differential equations subject to some initial conditions which I can solve using `NDSolve` (after assigning numerical values for remaining arbitrary coefficients):

```
{
    Mt x''[t] == 
     - k1 x[t] - k2 (x[t] - y[t]) + 
      mc rcm Sin[ϕ[t]] ϕ''[t] - γ x'[t],

    Mt y''[t] == 
     - k1 y[t] - k2 (y[t] - x[t]) + 
      mc rcm Sin[ψ[t]] ψ''[t] - γ y'[t],

    Inertia ϕ''[t] + 
     mc g rcm Sin[ ϕ[t]] + 
      γm ϕ'[t] ((ϕ[t]/θ0)^2 - 1) + 
       mc x''[t] rcm Cos[ϕ[t]] == 0 ,

    Inertia ψ''[t] + 
     mc g rcm Sin[ ψ[t]] + 
      γm ψ'[t] ((ψ[t]/θ0)^2 - 1) + 
       mc y''[t] rcm Cos[ψ[t]] == 0
 }
```

subject to the following initial conditions

```
{
    x[1] == 1, 
    x'[1] == 1, 
    y[1] == 1, 
    y'[1] == 1, 
    ϕ[1] == 1, 
    ϕ'[1] == 1, 
    ψ[1] == 1, 
    ψ'[1] == 1
 }
```

The system can be solved using `NDSolve`. Now I have two problems.

1. Instead of a single `ϕ` and `ψ`, I want to write down and find the solution for general `ϕi` and `ψi` with remaining parameters in the equations unchanged, and where `i` goes from `1` to `N` (i.e. instead of 2 coupled ODEs involving `ϕi` and `ψi`, we have `2N` coupled ODEs each involving a specific `ϕi` and `ψi`). Here `N` is input by hand before finding the solution. The initial conditions can also be defined accordingly. How do I write and solve for the same?
2. After this is solved, starting from the same initial conditions, I want to vary the values of `k1`, `k2` and `rcm` with some step size each time; and want to get the final values of `ϕi` and `ψi`  after some finite time. How do I do that?

Any suggestions will be greatly helpful.

Comment: You might get more help if you included parameters and more code.  When you say you want N pairs of ODEs, are those pairs coupled to each other?  Do they have same parameters?

Comment: @ChrisK sorry for the confusion. I did include the relevant parameters in the differential equations. What I meant by N pairs of ODEs is that I want to index \[Phi] and \[Psi] by using \[Phi]_i and \[Psi]_i, with the equations for them exactly same as the original one. So given some input value of N, I have total 2N equations involving \[Phi]_i and \[Psi]_i, with all being of the same form.

Comment: Could you provide values for parameters such as `Mt`, `k1`, `k2`, `mc`, etc?

Comment: @ChrisK you can give all these parameters some numerical value by hand and use NDSolve to solve the equations. For specifically k1, k2 and rcm; after assigning them some initial value, I want to keep increasing the value with a step size each time; and want to get the final values of [Phi]_i and [Psi]_i after some finite time evolution.

Comment: I believe `Table` will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use matrix forms to generalize your equations. since I do not have general equations for `xn, yn,ϕn,ψi`, can only generalize what you have given to me.

I start with the following vectors:

```
R = {x[t], y[t], \[Phi][t], \[Psi][t]};
Q = {0, 0, \[Phi][t], \[Psi][t]};
zero = {0, 0, 0, 0};
```

Then I define the following matrices:

```
A = {{mt, 0, -mc rcm Sin[\[Phi][t]], 0}, {0, mt, 
0, -mc rcm Sin[\[Psi][t]]}, {-mc rcm Cos[\[Phi][t]], 0, Inertia, 
0}, {0, -mc rcm Cos[\[Psi][t]], 0, Inertia}};
B = {{\[Gamma], 0, 0, 0}, {0, \[Gamma], 0, 0}, {0, 
0, \[Gamma]m ((\[Phi][t]/\[Theta]0)^2 - 1), 0}, {0, 0, 
0, \[Gamma]m ((\[Psi][t]/\[Theta]0)^2 - 1)}};
Cc = {{k1 + k2, -k2, 0, 0}, {-k2, k1 + k2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
 0, 0}};
Dd = mc rcm Sin[Q];
```

The final equations can be derived and solved as follows:

```
eq=A.D[R, {t, 2}] + B.D[R, t] + Cc.R + Dd == zero;
NDSolve[{eq, conditions}, R, {t, tmin, tmax}]
```

you can see that the elements of following vector

```
G = A.D[R, {t, 2}] + B.D[R, t] + Cc.R + Dd
```

would yield the the equations correctly, i.e.

```
G[[1]]==0
```

gives the correct equation for x[t], and so on. As next step, generalizing these matrixes would be easy since you only need to add terms regarding new `ϕ`s and `ψ`s.

Comment: Bruce Lee, Perhaps if you give the set of equations for `ϕ1` and `ψ1` and `ϕ2` and `ψ2` and how they fit with `x` and `y` equations, I can generalize it for you using my method so you can understand how to use it for large number of `ϕ` and `ψ` .

Comment: Hi, sorry for being late.  I will tell you the physical problem first, maybe that might be more helpful. I have 2 plates, bound to springs, moving in 1D, whose positions are given by x and y. Now I place n oscillators on each of the plates. The phases of the oscillators on the first plate is phi, on the second is psi. In the differential equation I wrote; I computed the equation for one oscillator on each plate, which was indexed by phi and psi.

Comment: Since the differential equations for the n phases have the same structure, so what I meant earlier was that the equations for ϕn and ψn are all same as those of ψ and ϕ, in their couplings and x dependences. So what I wanted was to write down a large number of differential equations with the same structure with ψ and ϕ indexed by n. x and y aren't indexed, they remain x and y only. Thanks.